# Is there vectorized string.format in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

From my research, I see that I can only use `apply` to format a string in Pandas, which is extremely slow in large datasets because `apply` is essentially a loop over the entire data. Theoretically, `format` is a vectorizable function because it does not depend on other rows. Therefore, is there any way that we can vectorize it?

For example, one of my work wants to do this:

```
joined["timestamp"] = joined.apply(lambda row: args.date + " {:0>2d}:{:0>2d}:00".format(row["tid"]/6, row["tid"]%6*10), axis=1)
```

where `tid` is an integer. Some sample data (`joined`): (`date="20170101"`)

```
tid       timestamp
 1    20170101 00:10:00
 10   20170101 01:40:00
```

I believe it is a common case to append a new string column by formatting some other columns.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) and change division to floor division (`//`):

```
print (joined)
   tid
0    1
1   10

a ='20170101'
b = ' ' + (joined["tid"] // 6).astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ':'
c = (joined["tid"] % 6 * 10).astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ':00' 
joined["timestamp"] = a + b + c
print (joined)

   tid          timestamp
0    1  20170101 00:10:00
1   10  20170101 01:40:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it out for this case, but what I really want to know is: is there a universal solution, instead of looking for all the `str` operations and write all the flow by myself?

Comment: @DarkZero - I think not, unfortunately. Vectorize `format` in pandas is not implemented yet.